# How to create a a Visual Studio Extension to get selected control properties?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a Visual Studio 2015 extension to get the names of all selected controls in the Windows Forms Designer, but I'm having a lot of trouble trying to reach the properties of the selected components. Using the code shown below I was able to get the name of the selected items in the Solution Explorer Window, but that's not what I need. Any ideas?

> ```
> DTE dte = (DTE)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(DTE));
> Projects projects = dte.Solution.Projects;
> Project project = projects.Item(1);
> MyStringBuilder.AppendLine("project.DTE.Application.SelectedItems:");
> foreach (SelectedItem selectedItem in project.DTE.Application.SelectedItems)
> {
>    MyStringBuilder.AppendLine(selectedItem.Name);
> }
> ```

Comment: Have you seen this tutorial? https://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005001.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I had to make a few changes because I'm using C# but it was a very valuable tip!

Comment: How can I mark your comment as answer?